# Conditional cumulative sum

Tags: r

I have this data frame

```
t<-data.frame(v1=c(1,2,1,4,6,7,8,2,3,4,8,1,2), v2=c(2,3,6,1,-3,-2,1,2,-3,6,7,-2,1))
```

Scanning the data.frame from top to bottom, I want to get the cumulative sum of v1 for as long as v2 is positive. When v2 becomes negative, it should stop, record the value (of the cum.sum up to then) and the cumulative sum should restart again from the next first positive v2 and so on. So that in the end for the above data frame would be be the vector

```
8, 10 , 12, 2
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you only want the sum, why use cumsum?

Comment: @Iselzer - Yeah, it seems to be more of a "conditional sum"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another way.

```
> r <- rle(sign(t$v2))
> diff(c(0,cumsum(t$v1)[cumsum(r$lengths)]))[r$values==1]
[1]  8 10 12  2
```

It's easier to understand if you split it up; it works by picking out the right elements of the cumulative sum and subtracting them.

```
> (s <- cumsum(t$v1))
 [1]  1  3  4  8 14 21 29 31 34 38 46 47 49
> (r <- rle(sign(t$v2)))
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:7] 4 2 2 1 2 1 1
  values : num [1:7] 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1
> (k <- cumsum(r$lengths))
[1]  4  6  8  9 11 12 13
> (a <- c(0,s[k]))
[    1]  0  8 21 31 34 46 47 49
> (d <- diff(a))
[1]  8 13 10  3 12  1  2
> d[r$values==1]
[1]  8 10 12  2
```

Similarly, but without `rle`:

```
> k <- which(diff(c(sign(t$v2),0))!=0)
> diff(c(0,cumsum(t$v1)[k]))[t$v2[k]>0]
[1]  8 10 12  2
```

Answer (score 5):

I changed the name of the data.frame because t is a function (transpose). I don't get why you want to use cumsum if you only want the sum.

```
dtf<-data.frame(v1=c(1,2,1,4,6,7,8,2,3,4,8,1,2), v2=c(2,3,6,1,-3,-2,1,2,-3,6,7,-2,1))
groups  <- rle(dtf$v2 > 0)

dtf$groups<- rep(seq_along(groups$values), groups$lengths)
library(plyr)
daply(dtf, .(groups), function(x) sum(x$v1))[groups$values]
 1  3  5  7 
 8 10 12  2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way:

```
t <- data.frame(v1=c(1,2,1,4,6,7,8,2,3,4,8,1,2), v2=c(2,3,6,1,-3,-2,1,2,-3,6,7,-2,1))

unname(with(t, tapply(v1[v2>0], cumsum(abs(diff(sign(c(0,v2)))))[v2>0], sum)))
[1]  8 10 12  2
```

It might seem a bit complicated at first :) 
The `cumsum(abs(diff(sign(c(0,v2)))))` generates a unique group id for each run of positive or negative values. Using `diff` and `cumsum` for this is a "common" trick that's good to know about... A snag is that `diff` produces a shorter vector - that's why the `c(0, v2)` is used.