# Conditional cumsum in R?

Tags: r, vectorization

Hi this an extension of the question asked here:
[Conditional cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537783/conditional-cumulative-sum)

Suppose I have the following vector. I'd like to calculate the running total of blocks within the zeros.

```
d <- c(0,0,0,1,3,4,5,-1,2,3,-5,8,0,0,-2,-3,3,5,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1);

Ans d <- c(0,0,0,1,4,8,13,12,14,17,12,20,0,0,-2,-5,-2,3,0,0,0,-1,-2,-3,-4).
```

I'd like to do it in a vectorized way as my vector is rather large. So far I have been trying to use rle to achieve this without much success.

Many thanks.

Comment: Probably there should be `...,20,0,0,-2,-5,...` in the second vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will work:

```
aux <- split(d, cumsum(d == 0))
v <- unlist(sapply(aux, cumsum))
1   2  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39 310   4  51  52  53  54  55   6   7  81  82  83  84  85 
0   0   0   1   4   8  13  12  14  17  12  20   0   0  -2  -5  -2   3   0   0   0  -1  -2  -3  -4  
as.vector(v)
[1]  0  0  0  1  4  8 13 12 14 17 12 20  0  0 -2 -5 -2  3  0  0  0 -1 -2 -3 -4
```

here `as.vector()` just hides the numbers of elements.

Comment: Hi @Julius my understanding is that sapply is prettier way of applying a for loop. Is there no way to do it without any of the "apply" family of functions ?

Comment: You don't need `as.vector` if you set `use.names=FALSE` in your `unlist` call.  @user1480926: you have to `cumsum` over the groups of non-zero elements, so there's no way to avoid loops (explicit or implicit).

Comment: Oh, totally left vectorization out of consideration.. @JoshuaUlrich, good point, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this should work. no loops.
very fast because all the work happens outside R

```
sum_from<-function(value,from)
{
  i  <- cummax(seq_along(value)*from)
  cv <- cumsum(value*cummax(from))  
  cv - c(0,0,cv[-length(cv)])[i+1] 
}

d <- c(0,0,0,1,3,4,5,-1,2,3,-5,8,0,0,-2,-3,3,5,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,-1)

all(sum_from(d,d==0)==c(0,0,0,1,4,8,13,12,14,17,12,20,0,0,-2,-5,-2,3,0,0,0,-1,-2,-3,-4))
```

results match:

```
> all(sum_from(d,d==0)==c(0,0,0,1,4,8,13,12,14,17,12,20,0,0,-2,-5,-2,3,0,0,0,-1,-2,-3,-4))
[1] TRUE
>
```